# Protect from SQL injection

Tags: php, filtering, sql-injection

I am trying to learn php and want to use a function to protect form agains SQL injection!
But somehow form record my db every data which contains any special chars like '"=)/()/*/

My filter function:

```
function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Register Page to get POST datas:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

Then i am trying special characters and form save them! What i an doing wrong?

Comment: It's fine to have those special characters.  `mysql_real_escape_string` (somewhat) protects you from SQL injection.  Those characters alone are not harmful.  They aren't what causes SQL injection, its mostly misusing single quotes `'` that expose you to vulnerability.  Also, I wouldn't call `htmlentities` when you are inserting data.  Only call this when you go to display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to protect against SQL injection, the best approach is to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared queries, where all user-provided data is passed in via [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (a_column, b_column) VALUES (:a, :b)");
$stmt->execute(array(':a' => $a, ':b' => $b));
```

You do not have to perform any manipulation on `$a` or `$b`; PDO will bind the parameters the right way, no matter which database you are using.

Comment: I'll add that [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) offers similar functionality.

Comment: Probably, but mysqli ties you to MySQL, where with PDO (assuming one writes portable SQL) you can switch to a different database engine by altering only the connection string.

Comment: You know, I'd much rather just use `mysql` and know the risks. And if/when `mysql_*` are removed from PHP, I'll just redefine the exact same functions that use `mysqli_*` instead. Saves me the trouble of having to rewrite every piece of code I wrote ever.

Comment: @Kolink If you're stuck with legacy code, then that's a reasonable approach.  If writing a new application, there is little use to use the mysql or mysqli extensions; PDO offers so much more.

Comment: Thank you! I will look PDO tutorials around!

Comment: @Kolink They are deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and removed as of PHP 5.4, so you might want to start rewriting.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder My working MySQL usage in PHP 5.4 begs to differ.

Comment: @Kolink Well I'm pretty sure they've been deprecated, so I'm surprised you're not getting a lot of `E_DEPRECATED`s.

Answer (score 2):

Erm... the point of preventing SQL injection is to continue to allow the user to type whatever they like, without it putting the server or other users at risk. `htmlspecialchars` is a good place to start, as it takes things that look like HTML tags and renders them inoccuous. The `stripslashes` you used is good, although the latest version of PHP removed magic quotes. `mysql_real_escape_string` allows you to insert anything in the database in the form of a string with reasonable safety.

So your filter function should look like:

```
function filter($data) {
    if( get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $data = stripslashes($data);
    return trim(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($data));
}
```

Now, if you actually want a *filter*, as in one that only allows certain characters, use a regex function such as [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg-match).

Comment: Thank you! I used regex function and it solved! My mistake i was thinking that filter function already clear them!

Answer (score 0):

Stop using mysql_* functions as they're deprecated. Use [PHP database objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead because PDO allows parameter binding which protects you from sql injection.

You can read up on using PDO [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score 0):

Also consider to check against regex if not using framework.
Examples: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/detection-sql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting-attacks

Comment: Unless you add more detail, this is better suited as a comment.

Comment: I'd be happy too, but I don't know how to convert.

Comment: You can add a comment by copying and pasting this and adding it as a comment to the question. Then delete your post by clicking the delete link.

Comment: Reputation under 50, can't see comment button :(

Comment: Yes. I always forget about that. Well how about you contribute a great answer or question to SO so you can get your rep above 50? :)